# How can I append my assemby version to the name of a folder, during the build process?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

When I do a release build of my application I copy all files needed to run the program to a folder. I want that folder name to contain the assembly version.

The build command I have partially works. I can get the version number into a file called tmpfile. The problem seems to be reading the version number from that file into a variable.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    powershell "(Get-Item -path  $(TargetPath)).VersionInfo.ProductVersion" > tmpfile
    set /p VER=< tmpfile
    echo %VER% > fileversion
    set "DIRNAME=FilterUtilityApp%VER%"
    xcopy /s /y "$(TargetDir)*" "$(SolutionDir)%DIRNAME%\"
    xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)Docs\*" "$(SolutionDir)%DIRNAME%\Docs\"
)
```

I have tested the lines where I read and write VER using a CMD window, and the commands work, fileversion contains the version number. When I run the build script, fileversion contains "Echo is on", which I assume means that VER is blank. There may be other problems with my build command, but I am stuck at this point of reading in the version number.

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you write *and* read the variable in the same command block...

Comment: Thank you, that works! I will post the answer based on you suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by aschipfl, here is the working script.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    powershell "(Get-Item -path  $(TargetPath)).VersionInfo.ProductVersion" > version
    set /p VER=< version
    del version
    set "DIRNAME=FilterUtilityApp_!VER!"
    xcopy /s /y "$(TargetDir)*" "$(SolutionDir)!DIRNAME!\"
    xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)Docs\*" "$(SolutionDir)!DIRNAME!\Docs\"
)
```

Note that %VER% is replaced by !VER!.